# How can I enable SSL in Azure Data Factory Oracle linked service that connects to an Oracle connection manager?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-data-factory, oracle19c

In Our scenario - We tried connecting to an Oracle host over a non ssl port and the connection was successful via the oracle connection manager which we were hitting and it was redirecting our requests to proper databases

Our DBAs then enabled SSL on a different port  and we used secret store and secret store password ( using open ssl method described in the attached official documentation) but were not able to connect.

What settings need to be done in order to make it work ?

Comment: Was the connection manager set up as an external listener for the databases, or is it used as a proxy with the entire connect path from client to connection manager to database server defined in the tnsnames.ora connect string? Have you checked the documentation, as here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/configuring-oracle-connection-manager.html#GUID-35D6C031-2F35-44FE-AA80-747777AE5AAF

Comment: it is external I assume because it is supposed to contain entries for other databases too. Also, we were not using tns file earlier for the non ssl connection